# Listnumber <ol><li> isn't showing up in IE9 after using float in CSS

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, css-float

I am creating a form with `<ol>`, `<label>` and `<textbox>` in asp.net
the form looks like this:

```
1. Question 1? ___Textbox1____
2. Question Number 2? ____TextBox2____
```

I want the textboxes to appear in same column (i.e. in same vertical column) like this:

```
1. Question 1?           ___Textbox1___
2. Question Number 2?    ___TextBox2___
```

My code looks like this:

```
        <ol start="1">
            <li class="qOpenEnd">
                <asp:Label ID="lblQ1" AssociatedControlID="txtID1" runat="server">
                    Question1
                </asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtID1" runat="server" />
            </li>

            <li class="qOpenEnd">
                <asp:Label ID="lblQ2" AssociatedControlID="txtID2" runat="server">
                    Question Number 2?
                </asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtID2" runat="server" />
            </li>
        </ol>
```

My CSS looks like this:

```
 .qOpenEnd
 {
  float: left;
  clear: left;   
  width: 100%;
  list-style: decimal;
 }
 .qOpenEnd label
 {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  width: 50%;
  margin-right: 5em;
 }
```

This working fine for Firefox, but in IE9 the number isn't showing up!
Any idea? The number WAS showing up in IE9 before I added the `float:left`, but at that time the textboxes weren't aligned.

Comment: You may need to provide a test case, try http://jsfiddle.net. Chances are high that there are things not mentioned in your code snippets that are causing your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your code output in my project on IE9:

[image: ie9 and firefox output]

Make sure you are in IE9 Standards mode, and not [compatibility view](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/How-to-use-Compatibility-View-in-Internet-Explorer-9) (hit <kbd>F12</kbd> to view/switch modes).

Comment: Yes, this IS what I want. But the numbers aren't showing up in IE9.
What browser are you using??

Comment: i m using ie9 too. this is the ie9 output.

Comment: Are you both running IE9 in standard mode?

Comment: @user713847: You may need to provide a test case, try http://jsfiddle.net. Chances are high that there are things not mentioned in your code snippets that are causing your problem. aliriza: This is just like saying the OP's problem really doesn't exist - is that what you're saying?

Comment: @aliriza adiyahsi: strange this isn't working for me :/ in IE9, but working fine in firefox.

Comment: @user713847: Hit F12 in IE9 to check.

Comment: @Madmartigan: cool. My IE9 was in compat view, after changing that to only "IE9" the numbers are showing up :D
But that means if user's browser is in compat view they won't see the number!!! Is there any way around this problem??

Comment: Yes, you can force the mode with a meta tag. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc288325(v=vs.85).aspx and http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/01/19/internet-explorer-8-document-and-browser-modes/

Comment: @user713847: No there isn't unfortunately. If the user has compat mode on, that's their problem. I don't think the meta tags mentioned above can change that.

Comment: Thanks @TJ. and Madmartigan that was really helpful